# Replacing Parts of String with Correction from Database in Java

Tags: java, ocr

I'm writing an OCR program in Java (using Tesseract to generate text from a label) and I want it to recognise common errors in the output, such as VV instead of W and NIR instead of MR which are stored in a database. So, for example, if it got a string like "VVEIN, MIR Adam" it should change to "WEIN, MR Adam".

What would be the most efficient way to check if the strings match any of the common error text? The only way I can think of at the moment is passing the string through a series of regular expressions for every known error, but I am hoping there is a more efficient way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Passing the `String` to multiple regular expressions will create a new `String` every time you replace a substring, since Strings in Java are immutable. Use `StringBuilder` instead.